# In "Invasive Species", why are the trees angry?

Tags: janni-lee-simner

I just read *Invasive Species: A Bones of Faerie Short Story*.  "Camden" says the trees are angry.

I read the full *Bones of Faerie* trilogy multiple times and I don't remember any of the Faerie folk mentioning that before.

In *Bones of Faerie*, Chapter 2, it says, "I knew those vines sought skin to root in", and "Plants used to be bound firmly to the places where they grew, but that was before the faerie folk came to our world".
On the next page, "Even after the War ended and the faerie folk left this world, the magic theyd set loose lingered, killing still".  This also does not sound like anger; it sounds more like a mine in a minefield; a dangerous weapon left behind by its wielders.

In *Faerie Winter*, it says about the plants they had called, "but then they'd attacked, because that was what plants did hen they were awake".  This sounds like it is just their nature, not like  there is some emotion in it.

So...

**What are the trees angry about?** (And, incidentally, why has no one else noticed?  But that is not really my question, as I am not sure it is answerable.)

Comment: [If I was a tree, I'd be F*CKING LIVID](https://static.dw.com/image/19055844_605.jpg)

Comment: *"We could head out before dawn now that the trees no longer sought human flesh and blood. It had been a welcome change not to fear every rustling leaf."* - I've not read this book, but a quick glance at *Faerie Winter* suggests that 'Faerie trees' are both carniverous and hate humans.

Comment: @Valorum - they definitely attack humans.  But I remember no indication that there was any consciousness; that was just the way the magic world worked.    At least, that is the impression I got.   BTW, I think the book is worth a read (even though it is YA).

Comment: It could just be an example of anthropomorphism, like when people say their car is lazy or their computer is stupid.